# splitting same category post for different styling - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, styles, categories

currently I am making a custom theme for my client and I am not a expert in this. My question is how to make different style for post from same category. Currently in my theme

Starting a New query for first post

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=1&cat=videos&offset=0'); if (have_posts()) : ?><?php      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="first-news">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('video-thumb');?</a><?php} ?> 
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,8); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

then again starting the same query for remaining 4 posts with another div and style

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=4&cat=videos&offset=1'); if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="second-news">
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('news-thumb'); ?></a><?php } ?> 
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,8); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

this working perfectly, Is this correct? I think there may be a good solution which will query post only once and get the required number of posts from same category with different style.
What I want is on below image.
[image: screenshot of current theme]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [category template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) from wordpress.

Before loading your page, wordpress looks for the presence of specific templates, example from the page linked above.

```
   1. category-slug.php
   2. category-ID.php
   3. category.php
   4. archive.php
   5. index.php
```

Comment: I know category template, Im already using this on my theme and I think there is no connection with my question. I shoul have more specific.  Sorry for misunderstanding my question

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate “post formats” in WordPress 3.1+, you will need to open your theme’s functions.php file and paste the following code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

Note: aside, and gallery are not the only available post formats. The available list of post formats are:

aside – Typically styled blog format.

chat – A chat transcript.

gallery – A gallery of images.

link – A link to another site.

image – A single image.

quote – A quotation.

status – A short status update, usually limited to 140 characters. Similar to a Twitter status update.

video – A single video.

For the full list of post formats, refer to WordPress Codex.
Once you have added this code, you will see a new field in your post write panel in the right hand column where you see publish.

Upon writing the post, you can change the format and hit publish. This will allow you to display your post in a pre-styled format.

Edit your post loop.

Suppose in your case videos category post format is **video**

We are going to be utilizing the conditional tag: has_post_format()

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) {

  // Blog Category format

} 
else 
{

   // Normal Formate

}
```

I hope this will help you. [More Info...](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)

Comment: Ajay is that what i want? I just want to style same category posts with different styles. eg: first post of video category show "this style" and next four posts "that style". Its a simple question I think. I just want to know is there any good solution instead of calling same category twice, for eg: some thing like <?php rewind_posts(); ?> . Styling can done by css

Comment: @Kanu This is proper solution, formatting post by category name or id is like hack, By using this method select post format for the category which you want and format it.

Comment: thanks Ajay, but I'm totally confused. can you make a example for above code? If I use same code specified on my question,(and its works great for me) will it be a extra load on mysql / server?. The site containing more than 25 categories, dozens of sub categories and getting pretty good traffic. This what bothering me.

Comment: somebody else here to help me? Just look at my code on my question and is it OK to use like that?